# Shortening/Making a function more concise

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, where-clause

```
flushPoints :: [Card] -> Integer
flushPoints cs@(c1:hd)  = 
    if flushPointsCalc True (suitCount hd) > 
        flushPointsCalc False (suitCount cs)
    then flushPointsCalc True (suitCount hd)
    else flushPointsCalc False (suitCount cs)
```

Let's say if I have a function such as the one above, how would I go around shortening it?

I was thinking of doing a `where hdFlush = flushPointsCalc True (suitCount hd)` but that I can't since hd is declared up above.

I feel that there would be a proper way to do it in Haskell, considering how lazy it is but I'm not sure where to look.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is exactly what the standard `max` function does: it choose the bigger value. So you can rewrite your code as:

```
flushPoints cs@(c1:hd) = max (flushPointsCalc True  (suitCount hd)) 
                             (flushPointsCalc False (suitCount cs))
```

If you just wanted to know how to give a local name for `flshPointsCalc True (suitCound hd)`, you *can* indeed use a `where` clause:

```
flushPoints :: [Card] -> Integer
flushPoints cs@(c1:hd)  = 
    if hdFlush > csFlush then hdFlush else csFlush
  where hdFlush = flushPointsCalc True (suitCount hd)
        csFlush = flushPointsCalc False (suitCount cs)
```

The `cs@(c1:hd)` pattern is in scope for the `where` block immediately under the `flushPoints` function, so you can access `hd` in it.

Comment: Ah, I was using maximum and for some reason it didn't work. But I might have missed a bracket somewhere.

Comment: @user1043625: `maximum` and `max` are different functions. `maximum` gives you the largest element in a list where `max` gives you the larger of its two arguments. You can see the difference just by looking at their type signatures.

Comment: Ah ok, I wasn't aware of there being two different functions(max and maximum) and thanks for the further clarification. :D